# PHP Composer dependencies conflict

Tags: php, composer-php, php-7.3

I have a legacy application with PHP 7.3 and Composer v1.
There is an installed `lcobucci/jwt:3.3.1` library.
The [requirements](https://packagist.org/packages/lcobucci/jwt#3.3.1) for this library are very straightforward:

```
php: ^5.6 || ^7.0
ext-mbstring: *
ext-openssl: *
```

Now I would like to install `auth0/login`.
The last version that supports PHP 7.3 is 6.5.0, and [has a bit more deps](https://packagist.org/packages/auth0/login#6.5.0), but nothing too special:

```
php: ^7.3 || ^8.0
ext-filter: *
ext-json: *
ext-mbstring: *
ext-openssl: *
auth0/auth0-php: ^7.9
illuminate/contracts: ^6.0 || ^7.0 || ^8.0
illuminate/support: ^6.0 || ^7.0 || ^8.0
```

I can install them separately into the empty project.
But when I try to install them together, I get an error:

```
$ composer require auth0/login:6.5.0 lcobucci/jwt:3.3.1

Problem 1
    - Installation request for auth0/login 6.5.0 -> satisfiable by auth0/login[6.5.0].
    - lcobucci/jwt 3.3.1 conflicts with auth0/login[6.5.0].
    - Installation request for lcobucci/jwt 3.3.1 -> satisfiable by lcobucci/jwt[3.3.1].
```

Confusion explanation of Composer doesn't help.
Why these libraries cannot coexist in one project?

Comment: Possibly because `auth0` requires `phpunit: ^9.5`, while `jwt` requires `phpunit: ^5.7 || ^7.3`

Comment: Try using `--no-dev` flag

Comment: There is no flag `--no-dev`

Comment: Well, for me `composer install --help` shows it.

Comment: For installing dependencies `composer require` is used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see on [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/packages/auth0/login#6.5.0) in the `conflicts` section for `auth0/login`, their maintainer declared a **general** conflict with `lcobucci/jwt`. That means, you cannot install **any** version of the JWT package alongside the auth0 package - when you want to use the most recent version of the v6 branch.

This conflict was added in v6.4.1, so you might try to install v6.4 by running `composer require auth0/login 6.4`